# Else If statement with numbers

Tags: javascript, if-statement

My code does not seem to be working and I'm not sure why, I'm knew to else if statements so maybe I'm doing this completely wrong. I need the user to enter a number and depending on the number they enter a statement is printed out.

Please see my code below, the error message I'm getting is "Undefined" after the user enters the number and presses enter.

```js
let waterPay = prompt("Please enter the amount of water you use to get a price you need to pay, thank you!");

if (waterPay > 6000) {
  console.log("The number is below 6000");
} else if (waterPay(6000 <= 10500)) {
  console.log("The number is between 6000 and 10500");
} else if (waterPay(10.5 <= 35000)) {
  console.log("The number is between 10500 and 35000");
} else(waterPay( <= 35000)) {
  console.log("The number is above 35000");
}
```

Comment: You should use```(waterPay > 6000  && waterPay <= 10500)``` instead

Comment: I'd suggest skimming some JS tutorials or looking around for what if-statement expressions look like--only one of these is correct.

Comment: huuh?`if (waterPay > 6000) {console.log("The number is below 6000");}` shouldn't this be ""The number is above 6000""

Comment: "_I'm getting is "Undefined" after the user enters the number and presses enter._" If you're using the code above, I highly doubt that you get prompted anything at all. It contains several syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look, it seems that the if-else-if is structured correctly. There appears to be an issue with your comparisons though. For example waterPay (6000 <= 10500) is not valid syntax. You probably want to write waterPay > 6000 && waterPay < 10500

Also make sure all your branches are accessible, ie that conditions don’t overlap

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [if...else page on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to see the expected syntax.

```js
let waterPay = prompt("Please enter the amount of water you use to get a price you need to pay, thank you!");

if (waterPay < 6000) {
  console.log("The number is below 6000");
} else if (waterPay <= 10500) {
  console.log("The number is between 6000 and 10500");
} else if (waterPay <= 35000) {
  console.log("The number is between 10501 and 35000");
} else {
  console.log("The number is above 35001");
}
```

Comment: `(waterPay <= 10500)` should be `(waterPay > 6000  && waterPay <= 10500)`

Comment: @Anonymouse If `waterPay < 6000`, the if-block will be entered and the `else if (waterPay <= 10500)` will never be executed. Hence the `waterPay > 6000` (or `>=` rather) is not necessary.

Comment: @Ivar oh damn i how could i not realise that, i feel so dumb rn lmao